# Git - change file

Tags: git, github, tags, git-tag

I've made new repository and made couple commits. I haven't pushed it anywhere so nobody cares  whether history changes.
I made mistake in first commit (the whole file is wrong) and I need it to change in all further commits (from the first, so all).
How can it be done?
If I already have some tags, will I have to re-tag them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the file and create the third commit. Then do: `git rebase -i HEAD~2`

This will launch the editor with two lines. Swap the lines and change "pick" to "edit" in the new first line. Save and exit the editor. This will apply the fix and stop.

Now do `git reset --soft HEAD~1 && git commit --amend`

This will fix the first commit. Now do `git rebase --continue`. That's all

If anything goes wrong, do `git rebase --abort`

> will I have to re-tag them?

Yes. Do `git tag -f <tagname> <commit-sha>`

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Just those tags, where I had a tag, the old version of file remained. Is there any way how to change it?